Convergence of $G_\epsilon \ast \phi_\epsilon (x) \rightarrow 0$?
I am trying to prove the following claim.
Consider $G_\epsilon(y) := B_\epsilon(f_\epsilon(y))f_\epsilon'(y)^{-1/2}, y \in \mathbb{R}$, where $B_\epsilon \colon \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of functions and
$$ f_\epsilon(x) := \int_0^x \exp \left( -2\int_0^z b_\epsilon(y) \, dy \right) \, dz, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
The derivative $f_\epsilon'$ of this function $f_\epsilon$ is the (unnormalized) invariant density of the associated SDE with unit diffusion and drift function $b_\epsilon$ which satisfies a local Lipschitz and linear growth condition. Moreover, it is assumed that
the derivative fullfills
$$ -b_\epsilon'(y) \leq K_1 y^2 + \frac{K_2}{\epsilon^2}, \quad y \in \mathbb{R}. $$
Thus far I have been able to prove that $\| G_\epsilon \|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow 0$. As a matter of fact, it shouldn't be difficult to get $\| G_\epsilon \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow 0$ for any $p \in [1, \infty)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Next, consider
$$\phi_\epsilon(y) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \gamma_\epsilon^2}} \exp \left( -\frac{y^2}{2 \gamma_\epsilon^2} \right), \quad y \in \mathbb{R}, $$
with $\gamma_\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. What I am trying to prove is the pointwise convergence of the following convolution:
$$G_\epsilon \ast \phi_\epsilon (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} G_\epsilon(y) \, \phi_\epsilon(y - x) \, dy \rightarrow 0, \quad \epsilon \rightarrow 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
So far, I have (unsuccessfully) used Fourier transforms, but in order to conclude the pointwise convergence of the convolution I would have to require that the Fourier transform of $G_\epsilon$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$; an assumption which I would rather like to avoid. I would be extremely grateful for any tips, criticism or hints towards literature.

Thanks for the comment! But the convergence should be pointwise. Perhaps I am missing something in your reply?

Is it? I may be mistaken, but I would argue that $| \phi_\epsilon |{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \backsimeq 1/\gamma\epsilon$.

It should be $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma_\epsilon}}$ but your point still stands

Is $G_\epsilon$ just some general function or do we have more information on it?

Thanks for the remark. It should be $1/\sqrt{\gamma_\epsilon}$, indeed. Well, yes, actually $G_\epsilon(y) = B_\epsilon(f_\epsilon(y)) f_\epsilon'(y)^{-1/2}$ where $B_\epsilon$ is a positive uniformly bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_\epsilon'^{-1/2}$ is basically a probability density function. I could add more details to the initial post if that is helpful?

You should add it... Maybe even add some information on $f_\epsilon$

Alright, I added some more details.

If $B_\epsilon$ is not continuous why to expect pointwise convergence?

True, I would be content with a.e. convergence, too. Continuity may be established under certain conditions, but they are super technical.
